# When I am using SQLite should I use a Query or Execute when trying using .Any()

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I want to run a query like this:

```
var exists = dbcon.Query<??>("SELECT 1 FROM Phrase WHERE Id = ?", id).Any();
```

I don't need to retrieve any data. I just need to find out if there is a phrase with an Id that matches.

Do I need to use a .Query for this and also then what should I replace the `<??>` with?

Comment: This query returns rows that contain a single boolean/integer value.

Answer (score 2):

Using `Linq` you can do that like this. It return `true` if **ANY** items exist in Phrase.

```
if (dbcon.Table<Phrase>().Any(d => d.id== AnyId))
{
   //yeah it exist
}
```